# mySql database doesn't read UTF-8 properly

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, character-encoding

I have an application working fine with special characters, except on firefox and when the app is online.

I'm using AngularJs as front-end and php/mysql to control my dataBase. When I insert new values to data-base, it convert special characters to something like this

> São paulo -> SÃ£o Paulo

The problem is, only in firefox and only when I'm testing it online, the output on the screen is show as `SÃ£o Paulo` instead of `São Paulo`. In chrome it works fine.

I already tried a bunch of things to correct this.

- Table in mysql to use `utf-8` instead of `latin1`;
- mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8;
- Convert data when going from AngularJs to php to `utf-8`;

But none of the solutions have worked to fix this problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: could you add some code sample ... eventhough I'm sure it's not the problem, it couldn't hurt to clear the basis

Comment: What type of code do you mean?

Comment: See if anything in here helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through in case you may have missed something.

Comment: Also already tried the code provided in that question. But the main, and weird, thing is, it only happens in firefox.

Comment: Has the HTML page the `<meta charset="UTF-8">` tag?

Comment: "Table in mysql to use utf-8" There's like 3 or 4 utf8 charsets in MySQL. Which did you use?

Comment: Yes, i did set utf-8 in my meta. Also, the table is using `utf8_unicode_ci`

Comment: the php part @CelsomTrindade

Comment: My problem had something to do with the one on the other question. I had to upgrad my server version (which i had to ask via support ticket to the provider) and also set the output definition. Now it's working. Thanks guys.

Comment: Search for Mojibake.